# CRM 2011 - Dashboards Slide Show For on a TV

Tags: slider, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dashboard

My customer want to have a "Slide Show" of all the "Dashboards" that are in the CRM.  He wants to be able to hang a TV out and then show a slide with some "Dashboards" that will change every 10 seconds.  The data needs to be up to date, so taking screenshots and putting them in a Powerpoint isn't enough.  I was thinking about the following :

- Create a custom Page with an Iframe and update the iframe every 10 seconds with a new "Dashboard" in it.  I know you can do the following => /OrganizationName/dashboards/dashboard.aspx?dashboardId=%7b16a69a12-105a-e011-bd7f-000c29198df7%7d&dashboardType=1030&pagemode=iframe, but there is no way where I can find the ID.  "The Copy A Link" functionality when "Right"-clicking on a view isn't there anymore.
- I remember at the "Tech Days" of CRM, that there was a possiblity to immediatly connect to the "Report"-server for showing the "Dashboards"... Or is there a table in the "Database" who has all the "Names" + "IDs" of the dashboards?? I can't seem to find it in the Database...

How would you guys make a cool "Dashboard"-slid for on TV (PC connected to TV is what I mean by that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a few screens in my office building showing dashboards from CRM, mainly Service Desk/call centre statistics.

I used [this 'copy link' method](http://gonzaloruizcrm.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/display-full-screen-dashboards-with.html) to obtain a URL to the full screen dashboard (without any  sidebars) then I  installed a plugin/extension for IE to auto-refresh and cycle through various dashboard tabs (can't remember what it's called, but if you Google I'm sure you'll find it).  This is always up to date and creates a slideshow effect.

Comment: Thx, I've did some research meanwhile and that's almost the same approach i'll be using.  The difference is that they will give me a list of the "Dashboards" they want in the "Presentation" and than I'll have javascript that will cycle trough all the "Dashboards".. For now I'm doing this in an Iframe, but I'll change to DIV's in the 2nd stage to have a nicer SLide Effect :) You can find all dashboards with NAME/ID in the "SystemForm"-table.. Which gives you the opportunity to create a "WebResource" that can talk to the "CRM" database and so you can easily get all ID's :)

Answer (score 0):

System Dashboards are System Forms and Personal Dashboards are User Forms so it cab be retrieved from dbo.SystemFormBase and dbo.UserFormBase tables respectively.

If any Personal dashboard is shared then that details can be retrieved from PrincipalObjectAccess table.

Use below sp to retrieve dashboard id, name and type for the specific user.

Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDashboardIds]
(
  @SystemUserID uniqueidentifier 
)
AS
BEGIN

select FormId as 'DashboardID',Name as 'Name', 'System' as DashboardType 
from dbo.SystemFormBase
where Type = 0

Union

select UserFormId as 'DashboardID',Name as 'Name', 'Custom' as DashboardType
from dbo.UserFormBase
where Type = 0 and OwnerId = @systemUserID

union

select UserFormId as 'DashboardID',Name as 'Name', 'Custom' as DashboardType
from dbo.UserFormBase UFB inner join PrincipalObjectAccess POA on UFB.UserFormId = ObjectId
where Type = 0 and POA.PrincipalId = @systemUserID

end

Happy Coding